# how to do for loop for each map key only in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I see that to iterate in each key value pair is:

```
map.forEach { key, value -> println("$key = $value") }
```

How do I iterate and get all the values for each key -  Something like...

```
map.forEach { key -> println("$key") }
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "all values for each key"? A map only has a single value for each key. If you want to iterate on all values ignoring the keys you can do `map.values.forEach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `myMap.keys` and `myMap.values` if you just want to iterate over one of those. And `myMap.entries` if you want the actual `Entry` object, where your `forEach` variable would need to be `{ (key, value) -> }` instead (i.e. a single variable with two components)